# Spark: Why does Python significantly outperform Scala in my use case?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

To compare performance of Spark when using Python and Scala I created the same job in both languages and compared the runtime. I expected both jobs to take roughly the same amount of time, but Python job took only `27min`, while Scala job took `37min` (almost 40% longer!). I implemented the same job in Java as well and it took `37minutes` too. How is this possible that Python is so much faster?

Minimal verifiable example:

Python job:

```py
# Configuration
conf = pyspark.SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")
conf.set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
conf.set("spark.executor.cores", "8")
sc = pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf)

# 960 Files from a public dataset in 2 batches
input_files = "s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2019-35/segments/1566027312025.20/warc/CC-MAIN-20190817203056-20190817225056-00[0-5]*"
input_files2 = "s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2019-35/segments/1566027312128.3/warc/CC-MAIN-20190817102624-20190817124624-00[0-3]*"

# Count occurances of a certain string
logData = sc.textFile(input_files)
logData2 = sc.textFile(input_files2)
a = logData.filter(lambda value: value.startswith('WARC-Type: response')).count()
b = logData2.filter(lambda value: value.startswith('WARC-Type: response')).count()

print(a, b)
```

Scala job:

```scala
// Configuration
config.set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
config.set("spark.executor.cores", "8")
val sc = new SparkContext(config)
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")

// 960 Files from a public dataset in 2 batches 
val input_files = "s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2019-35/segments/1566027312025.20/warc/CC-MAIN-20190817203056-20190817225056-00[0-5]*"
val input_files2 = "s3a://commoncrawl/crawl-data/CC-MAIN-2019-35/segments/1566027312128.3/warc/CC-MAIN-20190817102624-20190817124624-00[0-3]*"

// Count occurances of a certain string
val logData1 = sc.textFile(input_files)
val logData2 = sc.textFile(input_files2)
val num1 = logData1.filter(line => line.startsWith("WARC-Type: response")).count()
val num2 = logData2.filter(line => line.startsWith("WARC-Type: response")).count()

println(s"Lines with a: $num1, Lines with b: $num2")
```

Just by looking at the code, they seem to be identical. I looked a the DAGs and they didn't provide any insights (or at least I lack the know-how to come up with an explanation based on them).

[image]

[image]

I would really appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208574/discussion-on-question-by-maestromusica-spark-why-does-python-significantly-out).

Comment: I would have started the analysis, before asking anything, by timing the corresponding blocks and statements to see if there was a particular place where the python version is faster.  Then you might have been able to sharpen the question to 'why is this python statement faster'.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your basic assumption, that Scala or Java should be faster for this specific task, is just incorrect. You can easily verify it with minimal local applications. Scala one:

```scala
import scala.io.Source
import java.time.{Duration, Instant}

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val Array(filename, string) = args

    val start = Instant.now()

    Source
      .fromFile(filename)
      .getLines
      .filter(line => line.startsWith(string))
      .length

    val stop = Instant.now()
    val duration = Duration.between(start, stop).toMillis
    println(s"${start},${stop},${duration}")
  }
}
```

Python one

```py
import datetime
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _, filename, string = sys.argv
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    with open(filename) as fr:
        # Not idiomatic or the most efficient but that's what
        # PySpark will use
        sum(1 for _ in filter(lambda line: line.startswith(string), fr))

    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    duration = round((end - start).total_seconds() * 1000)
    print(f"{start},{end},{duration}")
```

Results (300 repetitions each, Python 3.7.6, Scala 2.11.12), on `Posts.xml` from [hermeneutics.stackexchange.com data dump](https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/hermeneutics.stackexchange.com.7z) with mix of matching and non matching patterns:

[image: boxplots of durartion in millis for above programs]

- Python 273.50 (258.84, 288.16)
- Scala 634.13 (533.81, 734.45)

As you see Python is not only systematically faster, but also is more consistent (lower spread).

Take away message is ‒ don't believe unsubstantiated [FUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fear,_uncertainty_and_doubt) ‒ languages can be faster or slower on specific tasks or with specific environments (for example here Scala can be hit by JVM startup and / or GC and / or JIT), but if you claims like " XYZ is X4 faster" or "XYZ is slow as compared to ZYX (..) Approximately, 10x slower" it usually means that someone wrote really bad code to test things.

**Edit**:

To address some concerns raised in the comments:

- In the OP code data is passed in mostly in one direction (JVM -> Python) and no real serialization is required (this specific path just passes bytestring as-is and decodes on UTF-8 on the other side). That's as cheap as it gets when it comes to "serialization".
- What is passed back is just a single integer by partition, so in that direction impact is negligible.
- Communication is done over local sockets (all communication on worker beyond initial connect and auth is performed using [file descriptor](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/28b8713036ff5ced4814d4d16d341f00b11ad3c3/python/pyspark/worker.py#L648)  returned from `local_connect_and_auth`, and its nothing else than [socket associated file](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4ec04e5ef3fbb0298762f372b688662a7ab2446e/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py#L195)). Again, as cheap as it gets when it comes to communication between processes.
- Considering difference in raw performance shown above (much higher than what you see in you program), there is a lot of margin for overheads listed above.
- This case is completely different from cases where either simple or complex objects have to be passed to and from Python interpreter in a form that is accessible to both parties as pickle-compatible dumps (most notable examples include old-style UDF, some parts of old-style MLLib).

**Edit 2**:

Since [jasper-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1374461/jasper-m) was concerned about startup cost here, one can easily prove that Python has still significant advantage over Scala  even if input size is significantly increased.

Here are results for 2003360 lines / 5.6G (the same input, just duplicated multiple times, 30 repetitions), which way exceeds anything you can expect in a single Spark task.

[image]

- Python 22809.57 (21466.26, 24152.87)
- Scala 27315.28 (24367.24, 30263.31)

Please note non-overlapping confidence intervals.

**Edit 3**:

To address [another comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60363908/spark-why-does-python-significantly-outperform-scala-in-my-use-case#comment106872087_60398928) from Jasper-M:

> The bulk of all the processing is still happening inside a JVM in the Spark case.

That is simply incorrect in this particular case:

- The job in question is map job with single global reduce using PySpark RDDs.
- PySpark RDD (unlike let's say `DataFrame`) implement gross of functionality natively in Python, with exception input, output and inter-node communication.
- Since it is single stage job, and final output is small enough to be ignored, the main responsibility of JVM (if one was to nitpick, this is implemented mostly in Java not Scala) is to invoke Hadoop input format, and push data through socket file to Python.
- The read part is identical for JVM and Python API, so it can be considered as constant overhead. It also doesn't qualify as *the bulk of the processing*, even for such simple job like this one.

Comment: excellent approach of the problem. Thank you for sharing this

Comment: Thank you very much for this anwser

Comment: The answer is correct only if you compare languages. But the answer is intrinsically incorrect for Spark because Python functions introduce a huge serialization overhead  in Spark.

Comment: The UDFs introduce a large overhead in the case of PySpark yes although there is no UDF invoked here! The above answer shows exactly why the language itself should not be considered a crucial factor for the performance specially when it comes to a distributed system such as Spark

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Hm, is Python is not invoked, how the code `filter(lambda value: value.startswith('WARC-Type: response')` is executed on Spark Executor?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis The execution plan in the question does not correspond to the code of the PySpark job.

Comment: @egordoe Alexandros said "there is no UDF invoked here" not that "Python is not invoked" - that makes all the difference. Serialization overhead is important where data is exchanged between systems (i.e. when you want to pass data to an UDF and back).

Comment: @user10938362 could you explain how it is technically possible to execute Python code in Spark on Java Executor. The only one way is to send it to Python process spawned on the same node.

Comment: @egordoe You clearly confuse two things - overhead of serialization, which is problem where non-trivial objects are passed back and forth. And overhead of communication. There is little or no serialization overhead here, because you just pass and decode bytestrings, and that happens mostly in on direction, as back you get single integer per partition. Communication is of some concern, but passing data through local sockets is efficient as it really gets as it comes to inter-process communication. If that's not clear I recommend reading the source - it is not hard and will be enlightening.

Comment: Additionally serialization methods are just not made equal. As Spark case shows good serialization methods can cut cost to the level where it is no longer concern (see Pandas UDF with Arrow) and when it happens, other factors can dominate (see for example performance comparisons between Scala window functions and their equivalents with Pandas UDFs - Python wins by much higher margin there, than in this question).

Comment: @user10938362 Spark uses pipes, not sockets, but it is not important. What you are saying is a speculation that the overhead of piping a serialized string to a Python process is negligable. It could be true if the function made heavy computations. But if you take into account that the function is very trivial, just a `startWith` check, the execution time is actually dominated by this overhead.

Comment: @egordoe "Spark uses pipes, not sockets, but it is not important" - would you mind actually reading the source before we continue? "Files" used here, if that's what you mean by "piped", are just socket descriptors. "What you are saying is a speculation that the overhead of piping a serialized string" - ditto, please check how "serialization" is performed in this specific case.

Comment: A non-Spark application that takes ~0.5 seconds including startup time, vs a Spark application that takes ~30 minutes...

Comment: And your point is @Jasper-M? Individual Spark tasks are usually small enough to have comparable workload to this. Don't take me the wrong way, but if you have any actual counterexample that invalidates either this or the whole question, please post it. I've already noted that secondary actions contribute to some extent to this value, but they don't dominate the cost. We're all engineers (of some kind) here - let's talk numbers and code, not beliefs, shall we?

Comment: The bulk of all the processing is still happening inside a JVM in the Spark case. Your example is a short running application in 100% Python or 100% Scala. That's very different from long running JVM processes where the only significant piece of code which actually runs in Python is `value.startswith('WARC-Type: response')`. You have a point that running in PySpark or Scala Spark should not make a big difference, but I disagree that this answers the question of why the PySpark code was significantly faster in the question.

Comment: The above answer starts with `Your basic assumption, that Scala or Java should be faster for this specific task, is just incorrect. ` the answer tries to address the hypothesis that Scala is much faster than Python or the other way around. It tries to prove that the language itself can't justify the ~40% difference between the jobs. I remind you that that was the initial claim...

Comment: The claim I see is `I expected both jobs to take roughly the same amount of time`, followed by the question `How is this possible that Python is so much faster?`. Anyway, I only meant to point out that _in my opinion_ this answer simplifies the problem up to a point where it no longer allows to draw meaningful conclusions about the problem statement in the question.

Comment: @Jasper-M I wonder if you'd be so kind and provide any specifics about which points you find too "simplified". As far as I am aware I described all points where contexts switch, and at least briefly discussed the implications. Also benchmarking is highly consistent with what OP describes, which provides good evidence that problem described here, is in fact the culprit.

In turn, the only responses I got so far, are either hand-waving or can be easily rebuked, and provide no alternative hypothesis. Not that I care much for the votes, but I am curious.

Answer (score 5):

The Scala job takes longer because it has a misconfiguration and, therefore, the Python and Scala jobs had been provided with  unequal resources.

There are two mistakes in the code:

```scala
val sc = new SparkContext(config) // LINE #1
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.executor.instances", "4") // LINE #4
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("spark.executor.cores", "8") // LINE #5
```

1. LINE 1. Once the line has been executed, the resource configuration of the Spark job is already established and fixed. From this point on, no way to adjust anything. Neither the number of executors nor the number of cores per executor.
2. LINE 4-5. `sc.hadoopConfiguration` is a wrong place to set any Spark configuration. It should be set in the `config` instance you pass to `new SparkContext(config)`.

[ADDED]
Bearing the above in mind, I would propose to change the code of the Scala job to

```scala
config.set("spark.executor.instances", "4")
config.set("spark.executor.cores", "8")
val sc = new SparkContext(config) // LINE #1
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AnonymousAWSCredentialsProvider")
```

and re-test it again. I bet the Scala version is going to be X times faster now.

Comment: I verified that both jobs run 32 tasks in parallel so I don't think this is the culprit?

Comment: hi @maestromusica it must be something in the resource configuration because, intrinsically, Python may not outperform Scala in this particular use-case. Another reason may be some uncorrelated random factors, i.e. load of the cluster at the particular moment and similar. Btw, what mode do you use? standalone, local, yarn?

Comment: Yes, I have verified that this answer incorrect. The runtime is the same. I also printed the configuration in both cases and it's identical.

Comment: I think you might be right. I asked this question to investigate all other possibilities such as mistake in the code or maybe that I misunderstood something. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @maestromusica did you try to modify the configuration for both clusters?

Comment: I mean yeah, I was printing the config to check if it's the same for both jobs and also monitoring # of simultaneous tasks so I knew `spark.executor.instances` and `spark.executor.cores` are not the issue here, I wish I made this clearer before

Comment: @maestromusica have you actually tried to run PySpark job you posted separately, with no preceding stages, as shown on the screenshot of the job plan?